# Accessing SQL Server using SQL login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, connection

We have a SQL 2005 server, which is running on a Domain controller.

When we access the database using a SQL login from the machine database server it works.

When we access the same database using the same SQL login from a different machine we get the following error message: "The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server Connection"

Anybody have any idea why we are getting this error?

Comment: Are you using SSMS to connect remotely or are you talking about an application using the login?

Comment: We have tried both using SSMS and the wizard on a UDL file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error, when we were connecting from the remote machine we were using the wrong server name.